# SQL Alchemy + WTForms FormField with default but don't insert empty data

Tags: sqlalchemy, wtforms, form-fields

So I have this wtforms:

```
    ProfessionalAddress = FormField(AdressForm, default=lambda: ProfessionalAddress())
```

which links a sub form to my main form. To make sure the subform shows up, I added the `default` behavior that creates the empty `ProfessionalAddress` if the relationship doesn't exists.

But the problem is that in some cases I don't need this subform and it is not shown, hence no fields are submitted.

But when I call `form = MainForm(formdata=request.form)`, as no fields are submitted, `form.ProfessionalAddress` is set to `ProfessionalAddress()` which generates an error as my DB doesn't allow empty entries there.

I could handle it at controller level (something like `if form.ProfessionalAddress is empty: form.ProfessionalAddress = None`) but it feels hacky, and I'd rather deal with this in the `Form` description.

- How can I handle this case?
- Can I differentiate the form generation case from the form population case?
- Or can I populate the default value later (eg. at view generation time)?
- Or is my approach completely wrong?

Hope it's clear!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to override the formfield's `data` property, forcing it to return `None` if all the formfield's fields' values are `None` (or whatever test you wish to apply).

```py
class MyFormField(wtforms.FormField):

    @property
    def data(self):
        data = {name: f.data for name, f in self._fields.items()}
        if any(filter(lambda v: v is not None, data.values())):
            return data
        return None


class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    name = wtforms.StringField()
    professional_address = MyFormField(AddressForm, default=ProfessionalAddress())
```

if we try it out

```py
form = MyForm(data={'name': 'Alice'})
for f in form:print(f)
form = MyForm(formdata=MultiDict({'name': 'Alice'}))
form.validate()
print(form.data)

form = MyForm(data={'name': 'Bob', 'professional_address': ProfessionalAddress(line1='1 High Street', line2='Dullsville')})
for f in form:print(f)
form = MyForm(formdata=MultiDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('professional_address-line1', '1 High Street')]))
form.validate()
print(form.data)
```

we can see that the form is rendered as expected, and `None` is returned if the professional address fields are not populated.

```html
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Alice">
<table id="professional_address"><tr><th><label for="professional_address-line1">Line1</label></th><td><input id="professional_address-line1" name="professional_address-line1" required type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="professional_address-line2">Line2</label></th><td><input id="professional_address-line2" name="professional_address-line2" required type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>
```

```py
{'name': 'Alice', 'professional_address': None}
```

```html
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Bob">
<table id="professional_address"><tr><th><label for="professional_address-line1">Line1</label></th><td><input id="professional_address-line1" name="professional_address-line1" required type="text" value="1 High Street"></td></tr><tr><th><label for="professional_address-line2">Line2</label></th><td><input id="professional_address-line2" name="professional_address-line2" required type="text" value="Dullsville"></td></tr></table>
```

```py
{'name': 'Bob', 'professional_address': {'line1': '1 High Street', 'line2': None}}
```